# Красивое добавление текста в TextView android

Tags: android, строки, textview, resources

Такая проблема: я хочу добавить текст в TextView, при этом  добавляемый текст должен содержать переменные (пример "Прошло $min минут и $sec секунд"). Как сделать это правильно?

При использовании строковых ресурсов - придётся разбивать текст на отдельные фразы/слова и потом в коде их склеивать тем же append(). Само по себе ничего плохого - но тогда возникают проблемы с локализациями, ведь если я переведу пример как "$min minutes and $sec has passed", к примеру - то ломается порядок строковых ресурсов, а соответственно необходимо обрабатывать в коде данные кейсы.

Возможно я что-то упускаю и есть более лаконичный вариант/best practice, как добиться желаемого результата.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете использовать переменные аналогично [`String.format`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Formatter#format-string-syntax). Следующим образом:

```
<string name="time_passed">Прошло %1$d минут и %2$d секунд</string>
```

И в коде:

```
int munites = 10;
int seconds = 35;
textView.setText(textView.getContext().getString(R.string.time_passed, minutes, seconds); // Прошло 10 минут и 35 секунд
```

Возможно вам понадобятся также работа с множественными числами:

```
<plurals name="minute_plurals">
    <item quantity="zero"></item>
    <item quantity="one">%1$d минута</item>
    <item quantity="two">%1$d минуты</item>
    <item quantity="few">%1$d минуты</item>
    <item quantity="many">%1$d минут</item>
    <item quantity="other">%1$d минут</item>
</plurals>
```

И в коде:

```
int munites = 10;
textView.setText(textView.getContext().getResources().getQuantityString(R.plurals.minute_plurals, minutes,minutes)); // 10 минут
```

При этом возможно придется-таки комбинировать несколько строковых ресурсов (для минут конкатенировать с секундами), тогда что-то типа такого будет:

```
<string name="time_passed">Прошло %1$s и %2$s</string>
<plurals name="minute_plurals">
    <item quantity="zero"></item>
    <item quantity="one">%1$d минута</item>
    <item quantity="two">%1$d минуты</item>
    <item quantity="few">%1$d минуты</item>
    <item quantity="many">%1$d минут</item>
    <item quantity="other">%1$d минут</item>
</plurals>
<plurals name="second_plurals">
    <item quantity="zero"></item>
    <item quantity="one">%1$d секунда</item>
    <item quantity="two">%1$d секунды</item>
    <item quantity="few">%1$d секунды</item>
    <item quantity="many">%1$d секунд</item>
    <item quantity="other">%1$d секунд</item>
</plurals>
```

И в коде:

```
textView.setText(
    context.getString(R.string.time_passed, 
        context.getResources().getQuantityString(R.plurals.minute_plurals, minutes,minutes), 
        context.getResources().getQuantityString(R.plurals.second_plurals, seconds,seconds));
```

**NB** Что касается множественных чисел, надо также учитывать, что для разных локалей набор возможных значений quantity может отличаться. Например, для китайского языка используется только other, т.е. по числам не меняется, а для русского языка zero и two не используются. В примере выше просто перечислил все возможные варианты, android studio подсвечивает какие варианты релевантны для конкретной локали).

ЗЫ Для вашей строки с моим примером будет проблема с "и" при отсутствии секунд.

Answer (score 0):

строковые ресурсы поддерживают переменные

```
<string name="error_api_server">Серверная ошибка: %1$d</string>
context.getString(R.string.error_api_server, code)
```

%1$d - где: 1 номер, d - численный тип

или например

%1$s - где: 1 номер, s - строковый тип